# Function that can perform segmentation on EMGU image

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I can get contours in Image with help of FindContours() EMGU function,
but I need to get from my image all kinds of contours , not just closed contours(lines, arcs, etc.)

Is there some sort of function that can perform strokes segmentation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sounds like you just want edge detection.  Try Canny.

Comment: I use canny,after canny I need to do segmentation to get unclosed curves and lines.